# Redirect to post after publish or update a published post

Tags: functions, permalinks

How can I get the permalink of a post from functions.php in my theme? I know this code:

```
get_permalink($post->ID);
```

but this produces something like this:

```
mydomain.com/index.php?p=123
```

and I need something like this instead:

```
mydomain.com/post-name
```

Is it possible?

I edit to post my code:

```
add_filter('redirect_post_location', 'redirect_to_post_on_publish_or_save');

function redirect_to_post_on_publish_or_save($location)

{

    global $post;

    if (

        (isset($_POST['publish']) || isset($_POST['save'])) &&

        preg_match("/post=([0-9]*)/", $location, $match) &&

        $post &&

        $post->ID == $match[1] &&

        (isset($_POST['publish']) || $post->post_status == 'publish') && // Publishing draft or updating published post

        $pl = get_permalink($post->ID)

    ) {

        // Always redirect to the post

        $location = "http://mydomain.com/post-type-slug/".$post->post_name;

    }

    return $location;

}
```

This are my rewrite rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

After see your code, I think that you are trying to redirect the user to the post after publish or update an already published post.

Your problem is not with `get_permalink()` function nor your permalink settings. Your problem is with the logic of your code. See how you set the value of `$pl` equal to the result of `get_permlink` but the returned value is the value of `$location`. Also, you are setting the value of `$pl` inside the `if` comparison statement, which is somehting you shouldn't do.

Try this:

```
add_filter('redirect_post_location', 'redirect_to_post_on_publish_or_save');
function redirect_to_post_on_publish_or_save($location) {

    global $post;

    if (
        (isset($_POST['publish']) || isset($_POST['save'])) &&

        preg_match("/post=([0-9]*)/", $location, $match) &&

        $post &&

        $post->ID == $match[1] &&

        (isset($_POST['publish']) || $post->post_status == 'publish') // Publishing draft or updating published post

    ) {

        // Always redirect to the post

        $location = get_permalink($post->ID);

    }

    return $location;

}
```

Comment: The weird thing is that i have it configured that way, thats why i dont get it.

Comment: And the links in the site what structure they have?

Comment: Like this: mydomain.com/%post-name%

Comment: We need more information. Please, edit your question and add the code where you are using `get_permalink()`.

Comment: I just added my code.

Comment: In the code you posted I don't see where the result of `get_permalink` is returned, you just compare the result of `get_permalink` with an unknown `$pl` variable. Can you tell us what is the result you expect from your code?

Comment: This is my current code because thats the only way i know to get the link in the format i want. I had tried with  $location = get_permalink($post->ID); but it didnt work.

Comment: The code I posted works here and redirect the user to the post published. Try it with no changes and let me know (`$location = get_permalink($post->ID);` it is not the only modification I made from your code).

Comment: Hmm no, it didnt work. Its redirecting me to the permalink in the wrong format: mydomain.com/index.php?p=123

Comment: I've tested the code again and it simply works. If you really have the permalinks setting set to `mydomain.com/%post-name%` and the `get_permalink()` function returns the URL of a post in a different format you may have a issue with a plugin or with any other part of your code. Difficult to say from here. Try to test the code deactivating all third party plugins and using a default theme.

Comment: I included my htaccess so you can see my rules are written accordingly. All my links look like: mydomain.com/%post-name% but still, get_permalink($post->ID); seems to produce a different result.

Comment: I've found only one situation where you are redirected to a URL in format `mydomain.com/?p=123`: when the status of the post is changed from published to draft. In this situation the redirection shouldn't take place but the code dosen't check for this change of status, only checks from draft to published. As the post is in draft status when the `get_permalink` function is executed, it returns the permalink with query string format, as it should for drafts. Tell me if this is what is happening to you.

Comment: No, my posts are all published. Also, its very weird because URLs in format mydomain.com/?p=123 redirect to an URL like this: mydomain.com//postname (please notice the double slash) and that is causing a redirect loop error i cant fix.

Comment: Are you saying now that you are redirected to the correct format URL but with an extra slash? You definetly should describe your problem more accurately. It is very difficult to help you with the information you provide, notice how your question and my answer have changed a lot. Even, I had to edit the title of your question to reflect your real question. Check the configuration of your site URL in WP Admin->Settings->General; it should be something like mydomain.com with no slash at the end.

Comment: I havent changed anything, i just added extra information just like that but its not relevant. The thing is that for some reason when you enter mydomain.com/?p=123 in your navigation bar you get redirected to mydomain.com//pagename which causes an infinite loop error, thats why i need to get rid of all the mydomain.com/?p=123 in my page.

Comment: We can not go to chat because you have not enough reputation. I'm sorry but I think you don't provide accurate information; now I don't know if your question is about the `redirect_post_location` filter, `get_permalink` function or with a general endless redirection loop. Please, think again in your problem and describe it accurately: what, when, how to reproduce it and relevant code involved.

Comment: We can go chat in stack overflow, i do have enough reputation there.